# using beforeSend and complete with $.post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

could one use the beforeSend() and complete() handlers with $.post or do you have to use $.ajax for it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have 2 options, use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Using $.ajax():

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Or, before your post run $.ajaxSetup(), but this affects all ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: myFunc,
   complete: myCompleteFunc
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This will work for complete:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
      alert("success");
jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

For beforeSend, you'll have to use $.ajaxSetup before calling $.post if you don't want to use $.ajax as they said before.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) but it will apply globally. If this doesn't fit you you should use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 3):

Gotta use $.ajax, unless you use $.ajaxSetup(), but that may not be the wisest choice.

Any reason why you shouldn't use $.ajax?

Comment: then i have to change all my $.post shortcuts to $.ajax. and they aren't few=)