# how can detect loading data in Jquery $.post method?

Tags: php, jquery, database, .post

Hello everybody i sent some value to php from Jquery $.post method and i want give some data from database

when load data from database is not completed show loading text and when load completed show data(It's contain some tables, div, text and image)

```
    var val = "";
    $.post("showData.php",{val: "loadMyTable"},
        function(response) {
            // if data loaded do something
            // if not show loading text 
    });
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2257987/3647441 - Show your loading text in `beforeSend` and show your data in `complete` callback.

Comment: Thank you, so ajaxSetup should become in function(response) {} function?

Comment: Where is _"loading text"_ displayed ? Could show "loading text" before `$.post()` call, remove loading text within `function(response) {//remove loading text}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your loading text in `beforeSend` and show your data in `complete` callback:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "showData.php",
  data: {val: "loadMyTable"},
  beforeSend : function() {
    $('#loadingText').show();
  },
  success : function(data) {    
    $('#loadingText').hide();
    $('#myNewContent').html(data);
  }
});
```