# how to use beforeSend option in $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm using ajax and I use beforeSend option in It .. But I want to know how to use 
beforeSend option  in $.post() ...

my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function () {
        //some condition 
    },
    success: function (){},
    error: function () {}
});
```

In $.post() :

```
$.post(url, data, function())
```

But when to add beforeSend option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using beforeSend and complete with $.post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257975/using-beforesend-and-complete-with-post)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than embed nested function calls, I prefer to them as separate functions.  Here I use BeforeSend to display an animated icon.  When the function finishes, I hide the icon:

```
function BeforeSend(jqXHR, settings )
{
    $("#WorkingGif").show();
}
```

If you are asking what the sequence of arguments should be in the ajax call, it doesn't matter.

Here's how I use it:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json",
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend:BeforeSend,
    complete:OnComplete,
    success:OnSuccess,
    error:OnError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), $.post seems has not `beforeSend` function.