# add loading text to javascript before html()

Tags: javascript

i want to add loading text before .html() load complete in my page

here is my code

```
  $.post("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/template-parts/live.php", { couplername:couplername, couplercount:couplercount, couplerlathing:couplerlathing, couplerwhois:couplerwhois, couplerdetailsname:couplerdetailsname, couplerdetailsid:couplerdetailsid, couplerdetailsnumber:couplerdetailsnumber },

  function(data) {
    $("#order_price").html(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have better control over your ajax call use the following ajax style:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    data : {
        someKey : "SOME_VAL",
        anotherKey : "ANOTHE_VAL"
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
        //HERE YOU CAN SHOW LOADING ETC.
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //HERE YOU CAN GET THE RESPONSE of AJAX
    },
    error: function (e) {
        //HERE YOU CAN HANDLE SITUATIONS OF ERROR
    },
    complete : function(){
        //HERE YOU CAN REMOVE THE LOADING
    } 
});
```

Comment: @MehranPourjenabi You can have a loading effect in the div in which you will be loading the new content and then replace all that with the newly loaded content, but the above given approach is far better. you can also go through the following answer for your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257975/using-beforesend-and-complete-with-post